# pg_restore relation error

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I am trying to run pg_restore on a file so I am able to use it in postgres. The file is a psql file. I try the command:  `pg_restore --no-privileges --no-owner -d test backupfile.psql -c -U postgres` but get the error that constraint x of relation y does not exist. I have tried different permutations of the command including without the `--no-privileges --no-owner` but continue to get error. Please advise

Comment: Do you think you could identify the exact command that causes the error?

Answer (score 1):

Since you specified -c, it is trying to drop all the objects first.  Apparently one of the constraints it wants to drop doesn't exist.  This error could just be ignored, unless you also specified -1 or -e (which you don't show)

But why not just start with an empty database, and not specify -c?